# Internet Explorer Compatibility different on localhost and local intranet

Tags: asp.net, html, browser, html5-video, compatibility

I'm having some weird issues regarding compatibility mode when I develop on my local computer and publish the website to one of our intranet servers. I'm currently using the following software for development and deployment:

### Laptop

- Visual Studio 2012 Professional
- Windows 8 Pro
- Internet Explorer 10

### Server

- IIS 7.5
- Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Standard Edition

---

When I debug the website on localhost:{random port}, I get to see the Compatibility Icon in IE.

[image: Compatibility Icon TRUE]

---

After I've deployed the website from my laptop to the server, I don't get to see the compatibility icon.

[image]

---

I need the website to show correctly for HTML5 content, i.e. Video in order for it to play. The video tag plays correctly on my laptop, but does NOT play on the intranet site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remember correctly, there's a weird "special" situation for intranet where some versions of IE pick up an unexpected document and/or browser mode. What may help is tell IE to render your site in the most up to date possible modes:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
```

There's a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/02/how-ie8-determines-document-mode.aspx) from the time when IE8 was the newest version, which shows the condition (somewhat near the bottom), where IE is forced into `Emulate IE7` mode.

PS. You haven't shown us any code which reproduces this problem (so the above is to some extent a guess). Make sure that your doc type is [set correctly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh920756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

PPS. I now see that the mentioned MSDN page in fact recommends *not* using the X-UA-Compatible meta tag at all:

> In addition, do not use an "X-UA-Compatible" meta tag on the page or send a custom HTTP header from the web server.